# Create plugin for cordova

Tags: java, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins

I try to make a cordova plugin.
I created plugin files with plugman.
This is what I have in MathCalculator.js

```
var exec = require("cordova/exec");

module.exports.mathCalculator = function (arg0, success, error) {
  cordova.exec(success, error, "MathCalculator", "add", [arg0]);
};
```

In MathCalculator.java I have:

```
package cordova.plugin.mathcalculator;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */
public class MathCalculator extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if(action.equals("add")) {
            this.add(args, callbackContext);
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("substract")) {
            this.substract(args, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void add(JSONArray args, CallbackContext callback) {
        if(args != null) {
            try {
                int p1 = Integer.parseInt(args.getJSONObject(0).getString("param1"));
                int p2 = Integer.parseInt(args.getJSONObject(0).getString("param2"));

                callback.success("" + (p1 + p2));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                callback.error("Something went wrong" + ex);
            }    
        } else {
            callback.error("Please do not pass null value");
        }
    }

    private void substract(JSONArray args, CallbackContext callback) {
        if(args != null) {
            try {
                int p1 = Integer.parseInt(args.getJSONObject(0).getString("param1"));
                int p2 = Integer.parseInt(args.getJSONObject(0).getString("param2"));

                callback.success("" + (p1 - p2));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                callback.error("Something went wrong" + ex);
            }    
        } else {
            callback.error("Please do not pass null value");
        }
    }
}
```

And in config.xml (I paste here just what is inside

```
<platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
            <feature name="MathCalculator">
                <param name="android-package" value="cordova.plugin.mathcalculator.MathCalculator" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <source-file src="src/android/MathCalculator.java" target-dir="src/cordova/plugin/mathcalculator/MathCalculator" />
    </platform>
```

I tried to call this plugin (after add it) in index.js like this:

```
mathCalculator.add({param1: 1, param2: 3});
```

But, mathCalculator is not defined.
I exported mathCalculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the plugin with plugman, then I added in bridge (MathCalculator.js) var

```
mathCalculator = myMethod: function (options, success, error) {
    cordova.exec(success, error, "MathCalculator", "add", [options]);
  },

module.exports = mathCalculator;
```

Then, in cordova I can call this method like this: cordova.plugins.mathCalculator.myMethod();

If I add in plugin xml insite `<js-module ...><clobbers target="mathCalculator"></clobbers></js-module>`, I can call my plugin directly with mathCalculator name.